# How can I place a limit on image ratio in CSS?

Tags: css

So ratios are a bit of a touchy topic in CSS.
I know how to set one up using the topic padding method. What I want to do is a little different though.

I want to allow the user to upload any photos they'd like, and I'll show it in it's ratio (so like height 100%), but I'd like to set a limit on that for a 1:1 ratio, so no one would abuse that and upload a super long image that would take away my whole feed. But if the image has a ratio of less than 1:1 (wider image) then that should be it's height.
Kinda like instagram.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't. CSS can't **detect** image size / aspect ratio...you'd need JS for that.

Comment: Yes, CSS can detect iamge siz

Comment: Put **any** feed (so images too) inside a container element of which you can control its height/width however you like. For images inside that container use `width: 100%; height: auto` and scale/size/clip it with `object-fit`. But how about posting a [reprex]? BTW: did you analyze the code/css instagram uses???

Comment: @RenevanderLende I don't have one because I didn't know how to approach this. I could have produced just fixed ratio one but I knew that this was not the answer

Comment: It is rather CSS 101, my guess is that when you can create code to let users upload images you would have known this already. Not trying to be unfriendly, just being a bit surprized...

Comment: No worries, I understand. I am self taught and just build as I go, never really had any guidance. This particular issue I haven't ran into before so was wondering if there was a solution.